Is there a way of Vector CANoe being able to take input via a usb gamepad and apply Input to a system variable?
I'm trying to see if it's possible to have a USB gamepad plugged into a laptop and then CANoe using the input from the gamepad to apply to a system variable.
From the research of done it seems like this may be possible by having a Dll file to handle the USB input and loading this into the CANoe config but I'm unsure of the exact mechanics of this.
Nothing attempted as of yet, just seeing if I'm on the right track with this or it's a lot easier/harder than I imagined.
